# VBA don't count Words in a Column

Tags: vba, excel, count, range

I am new to VBA and I wanted to make a code that counts some values from one sheet and writes the results to another one. It counts multiple columns in the sh sheet and every single resulting value should be written in a seperate column in the other sheet. The code works well for the first 2 values, but by the third value sometimes it gives me the right result but most times it just returns 0 like it dont count the column at all. Here my code:

```
Function counter()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("some_sheet")

    Dim k As Long
    Dim l As Long

    k = sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    h = k - 1
    l = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C1:C"&h), "Word")

    Sheets("other_sheet").Cells(1, 1) = sh.Name
    Sheets("other_sheet").Cells(1, 2) = h
    Sheets("other_sheet").Cells(1, 3) = l

End Function
```

Comment: `sh.Range("C1:C"&h)`

Comment: It works, thx a lot!!!

Comment: No probs, without sh. you are not saying what sheet to sum from, you are saying the active sheet.